# split string and convert to decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

got a table with the following data

input table

```
id metric_hex_string
1 '0x8000b0b07007ffff'
```

the hex_string need to split into group of 4 and then converted to decimal as below. Is it possible to get some some sort to automatic column names while doing this ?

```
id metric0 metric1 metric2 metric3
1  32768   45232   28679   65535
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no smarter way to split the string than simple `substr()`:

```
with my_table(id, metric_hex_string) as (
values (1, '0x8000b0b07007ffff')
)

select id,
    concat('x', substr(metric_hex_string, 3, 4))::bit(16)::int as metric0,
    concat('x', substr(metric_hex_string, 7, 4))::bit(16)::int as metric1,
    concat('x', substr(metric_hex_string, 11, 4))::bit(16)::int as metric2,
    concat('x', substr(metric_hex_string, 15, 4))::bit(16)::int as metric3
from my_table;

 id | metric0 | metric1 | metric2 | metric3 
----+---------+---------+---------+---------
  1 |   32768 |   45232 |   28679 |   65535
(1 row)
```